# Workbook.SaveAs method is popping Save As dialog box

Tags: excel, powershell, scripting, dialog, save-as

This was working fine until this weekend, now it's stopped..

I have a powershell script that opens an Excel file as read only, copies a sheet from that file into a new file, then saves the new file to a different location. The script still does all of that, gets to the very end, saves the file to the new location, but now it is opening a "Save as" dialog box, which prevents the script from ever completing. Something change with Powershell? Or the SaveAs method?

```
# Specify file names/paths
$sourceFile = "C:\source.xlsx"
$exportFile = "C:\export.xlsx"

# Open Excel, hidden/suppress alerts
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

# Open the source workbook in read-only mode
$sourceWorkbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($sourceFile,$null,$true)

# Create a new/blank workbook
$newWorkbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()

# Copy sheet from source workbook to new workbook
$sourceWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Copy($newWorkbook.Sheets[1])

# Save the new workbook
$newWorkbook.SaveAs($exportFile)
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify the XlFileFormat property of the SaveAs method ?
`$newWorkbook.SaveAs($exportFile, 51)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat

Comment: I found it...it was the workbook.close method...the first argument (SaveChanges) was set to true for the source workbook, but it is read only, so it was trying to save and prompting for a location. changed it to:

$sourceWorkbook.Close($false)

and that fixed it. It was previously set to $true, not sure why it didn't throw a Save As dialog until now...oh well.